# Firebase iOS - Array empty when called

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When my listener is called for my array it returns an empty array instead of the correct elements, why is this?

Model:

```
    var friendList = [User]()
    var removeFriendListener: ListenerRegistration!

    func addFriendObserver(_ update: @escaping () -> Void) {
        removeFriendListener = CURRENT_USER_FRIENDS_REF.addSnapshotListener{ snapshot, error in
            self.friendList.removeAll()
            
            guard error == nil else {
                #if DEBUG
                    print("Error retreiving collection")
                #endif
                return
            }
            for document in snapshot!.documents {
                let id = document.documentID
                self.getUser(id, completion: { (user) in
                    self.friendList.append(user)
                })
            }
            
            update()
        }
    }
```

View controller:

```
    FriendSystem.system.addFriendObserver { () in
        FriendSystem.system.friendList.sort(by: {$0.username < $1.username})
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        print(FriendSystem.system.friendList)
    }
```

Comment: It seems that `getUser` is also asynchronous, if that's the case, you should also wait for each and every `getUser` calls before calling `update`.

Comment: @EDUsta And what would the code look like for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would look like this:

```
func addFriendObserver(_ update: @escaping () -> Void) {
        removeFriendListener = CURRENT_USER_FRIENDS_REF.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
            self.friendList.removeAll()
            
            guard error == nil else {
                #if DEBUG
                    print("Error retrieving collection")
                #endif
                return
            }
            
            let group = DispatchGroup()

            for document in snapshot!.documents {
                let id = document.documentID
                group.enter()
                self.getUser(id, completion: { (user) in
                    self.friendList.append(user)
                    group.leave()
                })
            }
            
            group.notify(queue: .main) {
                update()
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically, for every document, a block will enter to the group, which will stay until `getUser` is completed. After that, when the group is completed, it will notify you, so you can be sure that everything you wanted to be executed is executed.

Edit: Removed `dispatchQueue` because it is unused, I myself was using it for the notify queue.